# Video recording in a SaaS

Tags: javascript, video, video-recording

I need a solution for recording video in my SaaS - right in the browser. I've been looking af this: https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record

But is there any better solutions for cross-browser video recording? Eventually something non-JS powered, third party software etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Hava a look at this. It basically allows you to talk directly to the users webcam. The user has to give permission of course.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia